# How can I delete files from a directory and its sub directories recursively in CentOS 5.6?

Tags: centos

I am using CentOS 5.6

I want to delete `.svn` directory from one of my directory and from all its sub-directories recursively.

Please help me asap.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$ find /path/to/your/folder -type d -name .svn -exec rm -fr '{}' \;
```